# Cordova Window Phone 8.1 Publish store

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, package, publish

How to package and upload cordova window phone 8.1 application to window phone store.
And will it run for window phone 8 or not ?
And what to prefer if we are developing for phones only.
windows platform or wp8 platform

Answer (score 1):

As @e666 said before, if you are using cordova CLI do build your project, than WP8 platform is deprecated. But, it is simples to package the project without cordova CLI. Just do the following:

*On Visual Studio, select solution configuration as **RELEASE**;

*Right click your solution and select **"Rebuild Solution"**;

*Go to your project folder/release and select the file named **"yourProject.xap"**.

*Log your account on Windows Development Center and upload the "yourProject.xap" you just created.

***DONE!** :)

PS: Windows Phone 8.1 builds wont work for Windows Phone 8. But Windows Phone 8 build will work for 8.1 and 10.

Answer (score 0):

The wp8 platform is deprecated so you should not use it. It will soon be removed from Cordova.

See : https://cordova.apache.org/news/2016/01/28/tools-release.html

According to documentation you can do this command line to build a version only for windows phone 8.1 :

```
cordova build windows -- --appx=8.1-phone
```

More infos here : 
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/guide/platforms/win8/index.html

Comment: and how to package it and upload it on store ?

Comment: With the command line I gave you, you will have the package. To upload it on store, you need to connect to your developer account on the dashboard and upload it : https://developer.microsoft.com/dashboard/overview

Comment: Last Question :)
And what about config , dont we have to set publisher id and all in that ??

Comment: Still on the same page of Cordova docs : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/guide/platforms/win8/index.html#signing-an-app With wp8 you didn't have to sign the app just using the good publisher ID. I am not sure if you have to do it for platform windows or not.